# Converting select statement to update (including exists & having)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

Im trying to change some records in my database but sadly my sql knowledge is a bit limited. After googling and reading stuff online I have managed to write a select statement in which i can find the records that I want to update but i dont understand the logic to write the update statement to do it. I have to make several similar update statements so I hope this one I can figure out the rest myself

This is the select statement I have:

```
SELECT 
    MG.id,
    MG.status,
    MG.fin,
    MG.execDateTime,
    EXISTS
    ( 
    SELECT 1
        FROM Mtask T
                JOIN MTaskHis TH ON TH.t_id= T.id
        WHERE T.tg_id = MG.id
                AND YEAR(TH.dateTime) = 2019 
    ) AS hasExecStart,

    NMG.id,
    NMG.execDateTime,
    EXISTS
    ( 
    SELECT 1
        FROM Mtask T
                JOIN MTaskHis TH ON TH.t_id = T.id
        WHERE T.tg_id = NMG.id
                AND YEAR(TH.dateTime) = 2019
    ) AS hasExecNext

FROM Management_Group MG
        JOIN MT_Groupman MTGM ON 
        MG.tgm_id = MTGM.id

        LEFT JOIN Management_Group NMG ON MTGM.id = 
        NMG.tgm_id AND YEAR(NMG.execDateTime) = 2019

        JOIN Management_Man MM ON MTGM.man_id = MM.id

        JOIN Location L ON MM.location_id = L.id

WHERE L.org_id = 69
        AND MG.stat != 'DELETED'
        AND YEAR(MG.execDateTime) = 2018
        AND MM.Type= 9
        AND MG.fin != 1
        AND EXISTS
        ( 
           SELECT 1
           FROM Mtask T
           WHERE T.tg_id = MG.id
               AND T.stat = 'execution'
    )

HAVING hasExecNext = 0 AND hasExecStart = 1
```

I know standard updates in sql:

```
UPDATE <TABLENAME>
SET <fieldName> = <value>
WHERE <conditons>
```

Except I do not know how to convert this select statement I have made into an update statement, reason for that is:
  - Where do I put the exist alias in the update statement
  - I also dont understand when or where to put all the JOINS in the from statement
  - What about the HAVING

What is the best way to do joined updates like this?

Comment: Why the `HAVING` clause? You don't seem to want to group.

Comment: I did that so I can see if a group has tasks done in that year.

Comment: I don't know but I suspect you want to push that into the `WHERE` clause (repeat the subqueries there, you cannot use the aliases there).

Answer (score 0):

In an UPDATE you can join the table you want to update to a sub-query that contains your current query.

```
UPDATE YourTable t
JOIN
(
   << add your query here >>
) q ON q.SomeKeyField = t.SomeKeyField 
SET t.FieldName = q.FieldNameFromSubquery,
    t.OtherFieldName = q.OtherFieldNameFromSubquery
```

Comment: I was thinking cant i just do 
`
UPDATE table AS T
SET T.fieldname =  'value'
WHERE T.id IN ( put my whole select statement in here)
`

Comment: @DatExchanges Sure, that also works. If you want to set it to 1 hardcoded string, and if the id is the only column in that select.  I kinda assumed you wanted to update some field with a value comming from the query, like f.e. status.

Comment: Hmm okay so then it wouldn't work because i also return other columns other than the id column. Except I dont know how to do it other than with exists in that specific select statement.

Comment: Well, with an IN or an EXISTS you can also update from columns of the table you're updating. But try with the JOIN anyway.

Comment: I didnt quite understood if you meant that I can just put my whole query in <<add your query here>>  part.

Comment: Now that I look at your query again, it doesn't have a GROUP BY.  A HAVING is normally used in combination with a GROUP BY to filter on aggregation functions like COUNT, MAX, etc.  Otherwise you'd just put those filter criteria in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah I didnt group because I already select only 1, maybe i have to revisit my select statement as well. Just would be nice to have a working update statement where i can base other update statements off with some tweaking for the rest of the stuff I want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191431/discussion-between-datexchanges-and-lukstorms).